# onClick not working on ajax generated content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My code doesn't show errors, but also doesn't work as it should. The output from the ajax call is working fine but I just can't get anything out of the `onClick`, no errors message, nothing.

**The HTML**

```
<div id="serials"></div>
<div id="accounts_info_key" style="text-align:left"></div>
```

**The Ajax call**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('.tab2').click(function(){
        var account_id = $('#account_id').val();
              $.ajax({
                 url: 'ajax/account_info_serials_ajax.php',
                 type:'POST',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 data: 'account_id='+account_id,
                        success: function(response){
                $('#serials').html(response.table),
                $('#accounts_info_key').html(response.key),
                $('.drop_down').hide();
                },
              error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
              alert(thrownError);
               } // End of success function of ajax form
              }); //end of ajax
       });//close trigger
  });//close whole function
```

**The PHP**

```
   $response = '';
   $response .='<div class="question">';
   $response .='plop';

   $response .='</div>';
   $response .='<div class="drop_down">';
   $response .='bob';
   $response .='</div>';

   $output_array = array(
              'table' => $response,
              'key' => $key,
              'count' => $count 
    );

  echo json_encode($output_array);
```

**The jquery onclick**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#serials').on("click", ".question", function(e){
        alert('smeg');  
    });
});
```

Please note, I am not asking how to do it, I am asking why my version is not working, it is NOT a duplicate question

Comment: Which `.click()`? The `.tab2` click or the `#serials` click?

Comment: I have checked those and the answer isn't there.  I am not asking how to do it, I am asking why mine isn't working

Comment: @War10ck, the serials click, the ajax is working fine

Comment: When the ajax completes, inspect the DOM using the browser's developer tools. Are you sure `<div class="question"></div>` is appending to `#serials` correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a fiddle that shows how it should be done in my opinion http://jsfiddle.net/6VtA8/.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tab2').click(function () {
        var account_id = $('#account_id').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/json/',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'something':'else'}
        }).done( function (response) { $('#serials').html('<div class="question ">abcd</div>'); });
    });
}); //close whole function 

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#serials').on("click", ".question", function (e) {
        alert('smeg');
    });
});
```

There are multiple reasons that could cause your code to not work. It could even be the fact that your div (from some css rule) would end up having a height of 0 and therefore the event wouldn't trigger. So instead of debugging I chose to do a little rewriting.

Comment: hi, I have class="tab2" for response, does it work? 
$('#serials').html('<div class="tab2 ">abcd</div>');

Comment: Tried in fiddle its not working

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe to the event click on #serials once it's in the dom. So when your ajax callback is over and that .question is in the dom, you subscribe to the click on #serials.

Comment: Shouldn't need to. `#serials` exist in the DOM on `$(document).ready(function () { ... });`. The OP is using a delegated event handler so it should be fine even after the ajax loads.

Comment: So what do I need to do that is different to make that happen?<<< ignore that